# Nginx pod not serving css files

Tags: css, nginx, static

I have a webapp running in kubernetes. I want to serve static files, css in my case, from nginx pod. From the application I define css file location like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

When building docker image I copy over css file to `www/media/` and in nginx config I point to that:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
COPY assets/ /www/media
EXPOSE 80
```

Here's nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://${FLASK_APP}:8080/;
    }

    location ~ /assets {
        root /www/media;
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the file can be found on nginx pod under `/www/media/css/stylesheet.css`, however I cannot reach it neither from the browser nor the application itself.
The error I get is this:
`GET http://192.168.99.106:30604/assets/css/stylesheet.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

`/assets` should point to `www/media` where the directory with stylesheet are kept, correct?
What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
Here's my Nginx config to serve the files:

```
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://${FLASK_APP}:8080/; 
  }
    location ~ \.css {
      root /www/media;   
    }
}
```

I also changed my docker a bit:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
COPY assets /www/media/assets
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /www/
EXPOSE 80
```

With the above config in place css is being served without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the solution, but hopefully some things to try.

1. Change your docker file to

`COPY assets /www/media`

2. In your comments you've said that you can see the files in /www/media. But you're trying to access them in /assets. Have you configured this in nginx correctly? Perhaps try this

```
location /assets/ {
    alias /www/media/;
  }
```

3. Final thing I would mention is permissions. What are the permissions of the files in the container? `ls -la` will tell you this. They should be `755` I believe for Nignx.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried everything you suggested but to no avail.

Comment: David, take a look at your flask logs when you try to hit the url. I have a feeling that your proxy_pass is at fault. So if the request hits Flask then there's your problem.

Comment: Thank Mark, your comments helped me figure this out.